# Can employers in Canada provide different Health benefits based on family or marital status?

Tags: employment, canada, british-columbia

My employer offers a health benefits plan where the amount that can be claimed towards the benefits plan is higher for employees who have a spouse, and even higher for employees with children. I am currently neither married nor have any children and have the lowest amount available to claim.

I can't find enough information to understand if this is legal.

After searching on the internet, I have found contradicting information online so far.
[This website mentions](https://www.kcyatlaw.ca/employee-benefit-plans-canada/)

> The ESA’s anti-discrimination rule prohibits employers from discriminating in their benefit contribution requirements and benefit payments between employees, dependants or beneficiaries on the protected grounds of age, sex or marital status.

However, I found [another page](https://www.ohrc.on.ca/en/iv-human-rights-issues-all-stages-employment/7-pay-benefits-dress-codes-and-other-issues#:%7E:text=Section%2025(2)%20of%20the,the%20ESA%20and%20its%20regulations.) that has contradicting information

> Section 25(2) of the Code permits group insurance and pension contracts between employers and insurers to allow for different treatment based on marital and family status, as long as they comply with the ESA and its regulations.

Comment: Do they also pay higher premiums for insurance? In general someone with multiple people on an insurance plan will have a higher amount of costs. In the US they also pay more for insurance.

Comment: Are you interested in BC? All the sites you cited are mainly for Ontario law. Federal law applies if your industry is regulated federally.

Comment: @JoeW Not sure I understand your comment. The employer pays our premiums and we just get X dollars towards our health plan per year that we can make claims against. I'm guessing the employer is paying higher premiums for employees with a spouse or children.

Comment: @xngtng Yes I'm in BC. I would think that the federal law would apply to my company. I haven't found a source that applies specifically to BC in regards to health benefits and discrimination based on marital/family status.

Comment: In the US Single employees are on different plans the those who are married or have children. They also pay more for their insurance as employees and employers contribute to the cost of the plan. I would guess in your case that there are also different plans and someone is paying more for the people with dependents then the single people without them. I think it boils down to what the insurance company is willing to cover which isn't something the company can control unless they want to pay more.